# Draw arc within polyline using bulge in THREE.JS

Tags: javascript, math, three.js, cad

I'm reading in a cad file from a dxf and I need to be able to draw an arc between two arbitrary points with a bulge value. I'm using THREE.Line to draw segments of the arc.

[This page](http://www.lee-mac.com/bulgeconversion.html#bulgearc) describes some of the necessary calculations in lisp but doesn't explain the center-point calculation very well. I also don't know what `angle` function does in the example code (Maybe the angle between two points using 0,0 as an origin?). Here is the code there:

```
;; Bulge to Arc  -  Lee Mac
;; p1 - start vertex
;; p2 - end vertex
;; b  - bulge
;; Returns: (<center> <start angle> <end angle> <radius>)

(defun LM:Bulge->Arc ( p1 p2 b / a c r )
    (setq a (* 2 (atan b))
          r (/ (distance p1 p2) 2 (sin a))
          c (polar p1 (+ (- (/ pi 2) a) (angle p1 p2)) r)
    )
    (if (minusp b)
        (list c (angle c p2) (angle c p1) (abs r))
        (list c (angle c p1) (angle c p2) (abs r))
    )
)
```

I understand how `a` (ie theta) and `r` (radius) are calculated, but I don't understand the center-point calculation and I need it (I think) to figure the segments for my arc. Can anyone help explain the math and/or provide some javascript code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A coworker was able to figure out what to do here:

In the lisp code, the angle `a` (aka theta) was just simplified to `2atan(b)` as opposed to `4atan(b)` because later we only need half the angle for some calculations of the center point `c` and radius `r`, not the whole angle.

The lisp `angle` function finds the angle of a vector (in this case, `p1 -> p2`) where 0 is the positive x axis, `pi / 2` is positive y axis, and so forth. That angle of that chord, plus the angle between the cord and vector `p1 -> c`, which is `(pi - pi/2  - a)`, gives us enough to do a polar coordinate calculation to find the coordinates of the center point `c`.